# Ошибка при выгрузке данных из PostgresQL в Elasticsearch через logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой:
при выгрузке данных из БД в elasticsearch вылетает ошибка

```
[ERROR] 2022-10-31 16:02:14.628 [[main]>worker1] elasticsearch - Encountered a retryable error (will retry with exponential backoff) {:code=>400, :url=>"http://localhost:9200/_bulk", :content_length=>137}
```

никак не могу разобраться где может быть проблема
мой файл конфигурации

```
 input {
    jdbc {
    # путь к драйверу БД "гуглится за 2 минуты запросом "
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/postgresql-42.5.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.40/win_base"
    # лог и пароль к БД
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "1234567890"
                # Можно настроить расписание выполнения индексирования, но у ме>
    # Я сделал обычную CRON функцию.
     schedule => "/2 * * * *"
    # Наш SQL запрос к БД, как видим может быть абсалютно любым.
    statement => "SELECT id as id, price as price, name as name from data"
    }
}

filter {
    if [action_type] == "create" or [action_type] == "update" {
      mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][action]" => "index" } }
    } else if [action_type] == "delete" {
       mutate { add_field => { "[@metadata][action]" => "delete" } }
    }

    mutate {
       remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp", "action_type"]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
    # название индекса в ES 
        index => "data"
        document_type => "_doc"
        document_id => "%{id}"
        #раздел типа действия
        action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
        #doc_as_upsert => true
        # путь к хосту ES и лог и пароль те что мы ранее создали в kibana
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        #user     => "db"
        #password => "MascasdaehaefwP"
        }
}
```

При этом если закомментировать filter и action в output, то данные выгружаются, но при удалении строк в БД, строки в elasticsearch не удаляются.
Заранее благодарен.

P.S. - в ES ошибок нет - если в output заменить action => "%{[@metadata][action]}" на action => "index" или action => "delete", то всё работает корректно. Но само собой action тогда захардкожен. Может это поможет пролить свет?

Comment: В дополнение:  
- в ES ошибок нет
- если в output заменить action => "%{[@metadata][action]}" на action => "index" или action => "delete", то всё работает корректно. Но само собой action тогда захардкожен. 
Может это поможет пролить свет?